# Description truncated in ShareDialogBuilder

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Using the latest Facebook Android SDK (3.5).  When I invoke a share dialog with ShareDialogBuilder the description is limited to 50 characters and is truncated with ... after it.  If I specify the caption parameter, the description does not show at all.  Is there a way to have a longer description than 50 characters, which is quite limiting? I tried to put in new lines \n and those were just removed.

Comment: Agree with you. have you find out the solution for this?